# iOS cropping and resizing ensuring rect stays visible

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

My app downloads images from a website. These images are all manner of sizes, from 800x600 up to 1800x1600. I analyze the image using facial recognition, and then want to resize and crop the image. However, it's important that the detected CGRect be visible on the cropped image.

I was using the excellent UIImage+Resize code and using UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill, but it doesn't seem to have a programatic way of specifying an arbitrary location that needs to be visible in the final image. So if a face is located at the 1600px range of an 1800x1600 image, it'll get cut off.

Is there an easy solution to this, or do I need to dig around in the depths of UIImage+Resize? Any guidance would be appreciated!